# How to load images with chained Promises

Tags: javascript, image, promise

I'm having trouble loading images with a script of chained promises - they turn up undefined by the end. I also have a 404 error I don't quite understand as I've confirmed that all the sources are valid, but admit I'm still a noob to debugging in an async context. **Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gromiczek/hz7rmnbc/) in question**. I've been chewing on this one for a couple days now and could use a nudge or two to get me headed in the right direction. I think this may be the problem area:

```
function loadImagePromises() {
    var imageLoadPromises = [];
    for ( var i  = 0; i < sources.length; i++ ) {
        imageLoadPromises.push( 
            imgLoad( sources[i] ).then(function(response) {
                var myImage = new Image();
                myImage.src = response; // response is a blob
            }, function(Error) {
                console.log("There was an error when the image was loaded after download: " + Error);
            }) );
    }
    console.log( imageLoadPromises );
    return imageLoadPromises;
}
```

As context, I'm writing an image loader script using promises for a Three.js program I have. No need to load the images to the DOM - I'll use them later as textures in a WebGL visualization.

*NOTE:*
Here's an earlier and simpler [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gromiczek/zfoorxcq/) working end-to-end and outputting to the DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably some other considerations here but your success handler isn't returning anything explicitly, so it's implicitly returning `undefined`:

```
function(response) {
  var myImage = new Image();
  myImage.src = response;
  // if you want the promise to resolve to a useful value put
  // it below, with whatever you want e.g:
  return myImage;
}
```

RE: Errors:
You should probably not shadow `Error` in your error handler, just use lowercase `error`. Also, when using `console.log/console.error` you can use `,` to chain parts of the message which usually presents a richer message than the string used when concatenating.

e.g.

```
console.error("There was an error when the image was loaded after download: ", error);
```

FWIW you could also reduce some of the tedious iteration/collection here by using `map` to map each source to a promise:

```
function loadImagePromises() {
  return sources.map(function(source) {
    return imgLoad(source).then(function(response) {
    // ...
    });
}
```

EDIT Re: waiting for image objects to have actually loaded

```
return imgLoad(source).then(function(response) {
  var imageURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(response);
  var myImage = new Image();

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    myImage.onload = function () {
      // image has loaded
      resolve(myImage);
    }

    // TODO error handling

    myImage.src = imageURL;
  });
}, console.error);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at this! So I return the array of promises at the end of the function above and pass it to Promises.all in the fiddle. Is it still a success problem in that case?

Comment: " Is it still a success problem " not sure what you mean there, but yeah your usage of `Promise.all` looks fine. But you tell me; what do you want to do when they've all come back successfully?

Comment: Cool. So what I would hope for is an array of three loaded images.

Comment: Ah, well to be sure the image object you have are actually loaded you need to also wait for them to `load` editing…

Comment: Not sure if threejs can accept an objectUrl, but that would save the extra step of loading an image for each texture and ensuring it's loaded, or heck, if it can take a blob then you don't even need to create an objectUrl for it

Comment: Sweet. I'm going to go script this, and I'll let you know how it goes. Thanks for the error message tip too.

Comment: Hmmm. Curiously the console is blank after the call to Promises.all. Here's the latest fiddle rewrite littered with sanity checks: https://jsfiddle.net/gromiczek/6mLgyxzh/

Comment: Success!! In the fiddle in my last comment I had mistakenly typed `myImage.src = imageURL;` one loop up and after the `return` on the loaded image. As a result, the loop cut off after the image load but the source was never added. Fixed it. Thanks for all your help and tips.

Comment: No problem. FWIW, you could also refactor this and move the image loading into imgLoad itself, if that makes life easier. And it might make sense to pass sources into `loadImagePromises` instead of relying on it being in scope i.e. these might make testing easier

Comment: Makes sense, and good ideas - I'll probably follow up on both. BTW, looks like I will need a different blob-to-source solution for Three.js, but that will warrant a separate question if I don't track down the answer in the meantime. Thanks again!